# Android get SecretKey entry from keyStore returns null

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore, secret-key

Get a secret key from keystore:

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
InputStrem is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my-keystore");
keystore.load(is, password);
KeyStore.PasswordProtection passwordProtection = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6});
KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry("alias", passwordProtection);
```

This works fine in Java SE. But for android, the returned secretKeyEntry is null. How to fix this for android? Tested in API level 28.

The keystore was created using keytool, and the secret key was added programmatically using Java SE JVM.

### UPDATE

In android, listing keystore aliases does not contain the one for secret key.

In java and keytool, listing keystore aliases contains the one for secret key.

```
        Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
```

Is there a way to convert PKCS12 to AndroidKeyStore?